# Visual Studio 2019 Web Application - Cannot Find Type WebApplication1.MvcApplication

Tags: visual-studio-2019, global-asax

I have a web application that i have downloaded from bitbucket that was created by another company who have handed it off to me.

The site is running live online now, however i cannot run the application locally due to this error message:

Cannot find type WebApplication1.MvcApplication.

The Global.asax file is:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

The Global.asax.cs file is:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Also the output path is set to bin/

The error doesn't seem to be with the code but visual studio locating the file global.asax.cs?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is it possible to share the sourcecode with us as a GitHub repository?

Comment: I dont have access to share the source code sorry the company who built the site have privileged code that serves their business.